# How to add values to database?Why getting this error Cannot use this in a static context?

Tags: android, database, static, android-sqlite

When markbutton is clicked i am trying to add these values to database through Databsehelp.java class.But when i try to insert an error occurs in Databasehelp.java class like **Cannot use this in a static context**.When i tried to remove static from databaseHelp class method i am getting this error "**Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method addprefloc(Locationdb) from the type Databasehelp**"

```
markbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Locationdb loc=new Locationdb();
            loc.lati=aa;
            loc.longi=bb;
            loc.places=titles;

            Databasehelp.addprefloc(loc);
        }
    }
});
```

In Databasehelp.java class

```
public static Locationdb addprefloc(Locationdb loc) {

    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("latitude", loc.lati);
    values.put("longitude", loc.longi);
    values.put("place", loc.places);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return loc;

}
```

The following code is used to handle the data

```
package com.bar.start;

public class Locationdb {

    public static Double lati; 
    public static Double longi;
    public static String places;

}
```

Comment: Remove `static` from `addprefloc` method

Comment: using "this.someMethod" in a static method makes no sense, "this" is an instance of your class.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i tried so getting another error

Comment: @HariSankar: Please share error which getting after removing `static`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it says  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method addprefloc(Locationdb) from the type Databasehelp.It says change modifier of addpreloc to static